# Online Sharepoint - REST issue - Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException - Error 2130575251

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, item-added

I am trying to save file to Sharepoint folder. This is my code:

```
public void saveFileToFolder(Folder folder, File file) {
    try {

        String token = getSPOIDCRL(folder.getSource());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        //calculate folder and file name
        folderName = URLEncoder.encode(folderName, "UTF-8");
        fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");

        String uri = folder.getSource().getUrl() + "/" + "_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'" + folderName + "\')/Files/add(url=\'" + fileName + "\',overwrite=true)";

        byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httppost.setHeader("Cookie", "SPOIDCRL=" + token);
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");


        HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(array);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Make the request.
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        // Process the result
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        //Parse the result if we were able to connect.
        if (statusCode == 200) {
        //.....
        } else {
            log.debug(getBody(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }
}
```

This is response I am getting from SP: Status code 403 forbidden.

> {"error":{"code":"-2130575251,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted.
>   Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation
>   again."}}}

I just calculated this token (it is not re-used) Same approach works for retrieving list of files in folder, for example.

What I am missing here? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UploadSPOnlineDocument
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                const string USERNAME = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
                const string PWD = "xxx";
                const string WEB = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx";
                const string DOCNAME = @"c:\users\administrator\Desktop\Test.txt";
                const string FOLDERURL = "/sites/xxx/Shared%20Documents/folder";

                //Reading document from file system
                System.IO.MemoryStream doc = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(DOCNAME));

                //Uploading document
                var t = uploadDocumentAsync(WEB, USERNAME, PWD, doc, FOLDERURL, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DOCNAME));
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Form Digest information
        /// </summary>
        private static async Task<Models.FormDigestInfo.Rootobject> GetFormDigest(HttpClientHandler handler, string webUrl)
        {
            //Creating REST url to get Form Digest
            const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/contextinfo";
            string restUrl = string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl);

            //Adding headers
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata");

            //Perform call
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(restUrl, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            //Reading string data
            string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //Creating FormDigest object
            Models.FormDigestInfo.Rootobject res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.FormDigestInfo.Rootobject>(jsonData);
            return res;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upload a document
        /// </summary>
        private static async Task uploadDocumentAsync(string webUrl, string loginName, string pwd, System.IO.MemoryStream document, string folderServerRelativeUrl, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creating credentials
                var passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (var c in pwd) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                SharePointOnlineCredentials credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(loginName, passWord);

                //Creating REST url
                const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}')/Files/add(url='{2}',overwrite=true)";
                string rESTUrl = string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl, folderServerRelativeUrl, fileName);

                //Creating handler
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
                {
                    //Getting authentication cookies
                    Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
                    handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

                    //Getting form digest
                    var tFormDigest = GetFormDigest(handler, webUrl);
                    tFormDigest.Wait();

                    //Creating HTTP Client
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", tFormDigest.Result.FormDigestValue);
                        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483647;

                        //Creating Content
                        ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(document.ToArray());

                        //Perform post
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(rESTUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        //Ensure 200 (Ok)
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error uploading document {fileName} call on folder {folderServerRelativeUrl}. {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Models
    {
        public class FormDigestInfo
        {
            public class Rootobject
            {
                public int FormDigestTimeoutSeconds { get; set; }
                public string FormDigestValue { get; set; }
                public string LibraryVersion { get; set; }
                public string SiteFullUrl { get; set; }
                public string[] SupportedSchemaVersions { get; set; }
                public string WebFullUrl { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```